# Can I mapping network drive in very special way using winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, net-use

I have to start my application with admin privileges ( very important ).

When I execute this code without admin privileges everything is perfect. There is an icon in MyComputer.

```
NETRESOURCE nrServer;
memset(&nrServer, 0, sizeof (NETRESOURCE));
nrServer.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
nrServer.lpLocalName = L"S:";
nrServer.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\192.168.32.36\\folderName";
nrServer.lpProvider = L"";
auto dwError = WNetAddConnection2(&nrServer, L"user", L"pass", 0);
```

But when I execute this code above in application with admin privileges, there is no icon in MyComputer.

I think that can be usefull:
[Mapped network drives are not showing in My Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435699/mapped-network-drives-are-not-showing-in-my-computer)

Is there any way to execute winapi function as not admin when my application has admin privileges?

Comment: Drive mappings are setup on a per-user basis. When you run your code as an admin, it is likely running as a different user than the one who is looking at Explorer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you Remy for answer. You are the best. So do you see any way to mapping disk from application which has admin privileges?

Comment: Your code running as admin will have to spawn a new process that runs as the user who is logged in to the current Windows session, and then that new process can create the mapping. See [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) and [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443) on Raymond Chen's blog

Comment: The alternative is not run your whole app as an admin to begin with, but instead have it elevate dynamically (via a new process) only when it needs to perform admin tasks.

Comment: That should be the starting point, not an alternative.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have to read this article, but thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I have to run netsh cmd command in my application. I use QT, so I use qprocess->start(R"(netsh …………...)"). When I don't execute my app with admin privileges that command don't be executed properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you tell me how to run only choosen by me processes, which have to be with admin privileges and started my app without them? Something like runas administator cmdCommand?

Comment: The [1st article I pointed you to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) tells you how to run an elevated process from an un-elevated process: "*Going from an unelevated process to an elevated process is easy. You can run a process with elevation by passing the `runas` verb
to `Shell­Execute` or `Shell­Execute­Ex`.*" To prevent your main app from running as an admin, simply specify `asInvoker` instead of `requireAdministrator` in its UAC manifest. But that won't stop an admin from using "Run as Administrator" on the EXE, if they really want to

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have a small problem with InitializeProcThreadAttributeList function. I get information "use of undeclared indentifier InitializeProcThreadAttributeList ". When I go to processthreadsapi.h I see  that function, but It is not active because #if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600 is not true. I read that can be because of include order.

Comment: It means your project is not setup to compile for Vista+. So fix your project setup (which means your code may not run on XP and earlier anymore, if you still need that), see [Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt) and [Update WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019). Otherwise, load `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList()` dynamically at runtime using `GetProcAddress()`. `STARTUPINFOEX` was introduced in Vista.

Comment: yes, this possible, but require not small code. need impersonate not elevated user token before call `WNetAddConnection2`. for this need first get TCB privilege. this is possible if you run as admin (more exactly if you have debug privilege)

Comment: not need run new process of course

Comment: @RemyLebeau -*Drive mappings are setup on a per-user basis* - this is wrong. per session locally unique identifier ( LUID) basis. admin usually run as same user like explorer, but in another logon session. with another luid. but anyway not need exec new process for task

Comment: @RbMm "*per session locally unique identifier (LUID) basis*" - same thing. Separate user sessions = separate mappings storage. "*admin usually run as same user like explorer*" - you can't rely on that, though. Sure, if you own the PC, you are likely your own admin and can elevate yourself when needed. But in a corporate environment, that is usually not the case. So if the Windows Session user and the admin user are actually two different users, then yes, you should use another process, or impersonation like you say.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes admin can be different user and can be the same user as explorer(shell). but this is not important for solution. anyway elevated admin will be run in another logon session. i try say - it not per user basis but per token luid bases. also *if `LocalSystem` calls the `WNetAddConnection2` function, then the mapped drive is visible to all user logon sessions.* and we easy can impersonate as *LocalSystem* too. not need separate process

Answer (score 0):

from [`WNetAddConnection2W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w)

> *the WNet functions create and delete network drive letters in the MS-DOS device namespace associated with a **logon session** because
> MS-DOS devices are identified by AuthenticationID (a locally unique
> identifier, or LUID, associated with a logon session.)*

also

> *if a code that runs as **LocalSystem** calls the `WNetAddConnection2` function, then the mapped drive is visible to all
> user logon sessions.*

technically this mean if code run as **LocalSystem** in the `\GLOBAL??\` folder will be create symbolic link to network disk. otherwise link will be created under

`\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<token LogonId>\`

and will be visible only for threads(processes) which have the same LogonId in token

if your code have admin privileges - it usually (almost always) have debug privileges. with this we can open process with *LocalSystem* token and impersonate it before call `WNetAddConnection2`.

possible also get TCB privilege and after this call [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken), convert primary token to impersonation token, via [`DuplicateToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-duplicatetoken), and impersonate - [`SetThreadToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadtoken). and call `WNetAddConnection2` finally.

ok. i try first simply impersonate to *LocalSystem*

let we have function

```
NTSTATUS ImpersonateSystemOrTcbToken(bool bTcb);
```

which set *LocalSystem* or token with *Tcb* privileges to current thread (as far i know all *LocalSystem* tokens have TCB privilege but anyway write 2 different code for get exactly token with *TCB* or with *LocalSystem*)

and

```
HRESULT AdjustDebugPrivilegesToThread();
```

which enable debug privileges in current thread token (it must exist in admin token)

in this case code can be next:

```
inline HRESULT BOOL_TO_HRESULT(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

HRESULT MapRemoteDrive(PCWSTR local, PCWSTR remote, PCWSTR username, PCWSTR password)
{
    NETRESOURCEW nr = {
        0, RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 0, 0, const_cast<PWSTR>(local), const_cast<PWSTR>(remote)
    };
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(WNetAddConnection2W(&nr, password, username, 0));
}

HRESULT MapRemoteDriveEx1(PCWSTR local, PCWSTR remote, PCWSTR username, PCWSTR password)
{
    HRESULT hr = BOOL_TO_HRESULT(ImpersonateSelf(::SecurityImpersonation));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = AdjustDebugPrivilegesToThread()) &&
            SUCCEEDED(hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(ImpersonateSystemOrTcbToken(false))))
        {
            hr = MapRemoteDrive(local, remote, username, password);
            // WNetCancelConnection2W(local, 0, TRUE);
        }

        SetThreadToken(0, 0);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

code work ok and really network location created, but with next view:

[image]

despite this - drive is browsed correct on click. i not research why is **Disconected** word in description. but possible some problems with permissions here

if try create drive for concrete LUID, code will be more complex

```
HRESULT MapRemoteDriveEx2(PCWSTR local, PCWSTR remote, PCWSTR username, PCWSTR password)
{
    HRESULT hr = BOOL_TO_HRESULT(ImpersonateSelf(::SecurityImpersonation));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        HANDLE hToken, hImpToken;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = AdjustDebugPrivilegesToThread()) &&
            SUCCEEDED(hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(ImpersonateSystemOrTcbToken(true))) &&
            SUCCEEDED(hr = BOOL_TO_HRESULT(WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), &hToken))))
        {
            hr = BOOL_TO_HRESULT(DuplicateToken(hToken, ::SecurityImpersonation, &hImpToken));
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = BOOL_TO_HRESULT(SetThreadToken(0, hImpToken));
                CloseHandle(hImpToken);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = MapRemoteDrive(local, remote, username, password);
                    // WNetCancelConnection2W(local, 0, TRUE);
                }
            }
        }

        SetThreadToken(0, 0);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

with this result full ok

[image]

now code for util functions:

```
HRESULT AdjustDebugPrivilegesToThread()
{
    ULONG dwError;
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenThreadToken(NtCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, TRUE, &hToken))
    {
        static const ::TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 1, { { { SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE } } } };

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, const_cast<::PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(&tp), 0, 0, 0);

        dwError = GetLastError();

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
}
```

and..

```
NTSTATUS GetSystemToken(PVOID buf)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    pv = buf;
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do 
    {
        pb += NextEntryOffset;

        HANDLE hProcess, hToken, hNewToken;

        CLIENT_ID ClientId = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

        if (ClientId.UniqueProcess)
        {
            static SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
                sizeof sqos, SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
            };

            static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES soa = { sizeof(soa), 0, 0, 0, 0, &sqos };

            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &ClientId))
            {
                status = NtOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);

                NtClose(hProcess);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    ULONG rcb;
                    TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
                    static const LUID SystemLuid = SYSTEM_LUID;

                    status = -1;

                    if (0 <= NtQueryInformationToken(hToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &rcb) &&
                        ts.AuthenticationId.LowPart == SystemLuid.LowPart &&
                        ts.AuthenticationId.HighPart == SystemLuid.HighPart)
                    {
                        status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
                            &soa, FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);
                    }

                    NtClose(hToken);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hNewToken, sizeof(hNewToken));
                        
                        NtClose(hNewToken);

                        return status;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

NTSTATUS GetTcbToken(PVOID buf)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    pv = buf;
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do 
    {
        pb += NextEntryOffset;

        HANDLE hProcess, hToken, hNewToken;

        if (pspi->InheritedFromUniqueProcessId && pspi->UniqueProcessId)
        {
            static SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
                sizeof sqos, SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
            };

            static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES soa = { sizeof(soa), 0, 0, 0, 0, &sqos };

            CLIENT_ID ClientId = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &ClientId))
            {
                status = NtOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);

                NtClose(hProcess);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
                        &soa, FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);

                    NtClose(hToken);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        static const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 1, { { { SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE } } } };

                        status = NtAdjustPrivilegesToken(hNewToken, FALSE, const_cast<PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(&tp), 0, 0, 0);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)   
                        {
                            status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hNewToken, sizeof(hNewToken));
                        }

                        NtClose(hNewToken);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)
                        {
                            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

NTSTATUS ImpersonateSystemOrTcbToken(bool bTcb)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x10000;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PBYTE buf = new BYTE[cb += 0x1000])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                status = (bTcb ? GetTcbToken : GetSystemToken)(buf);

                if (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                }
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while(status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomaszNowakowski You could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it does help you.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT How? I don't see button "solved". I can't add point to RbMm because I don't have 15 points reputation.

Comment: How/Why is `FALSE` passed to 4th argument of `NtDuplicateToken`, which expects `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`. This doesn't compile on C++. If FALSE/0 is passed, are you implying `SecurityAnonymous`?

Comment: @Ajay 4th argument of NtDuplicateToken is *_In_ BOOLEAN EffectiveOnly,* (look in *ntifs.h*) my code of course compiled. the `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` is passed via 3th argument `POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` where exist pointer to `SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE` and here exist `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` - i use here `SecurityImpersonation`

Comment: @Ajay i think you confuse `DuplicateTokenEx` (which really take `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` in 4th argument) and `NtDuplicateToken` which have another signature and take `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` from `SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE ` inside `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` (pointer to this in 3th argument)